# Iteration over features in PyQGIS processing modules

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-processing, loop, iteration

I have an issue with `processing.run` commands where I would like to do an iteration over features in a layer with polygons.

```
zsj = QgsVectorLayer("/data/grassmaster/testVlado/zsj_ba_test.gpkg", "zsj", "or")

si = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("Vectorized")[0]

it = zsj.getFeatures()

for i in it:

    clip = processing.run("qgis:clip", {'INPUT':si, 'OVERLAY':it[i], 'OUTPUT':'memory:'})
    print(clip['OUTPUT'])
```

Here is the error:

```
TypeError: 'QgsFeatureIterator' object is not subscriptable
```

How can I use this processing command for individual features in the layer? Respectively, how can I save a feature in the layer as a new (memory) layer?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, for me would be probably helpful to save the feature as a layer and iterate it with each feature in the original layer. I can't find the manual on how to save feature from one layer to another one.

Answer (score 1):

I've made a recipe trying to reuse your variables

```py
zsj = QgsVectorLayer("/data/grassmaster/testVlado/zsj_ba_test.gpkg", "zsj", "or")

si = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("Vectorized")[0]

# Dict to then get layer type when declaring in memory layer
layerTypes = {
    getattr(QgsWkbTypes, i): i for i in [
    'Point',
    'LineString',
    'Polygon',
    'MultiPoint',
    'MultiLineString',
    'MultiPolygon'
]}

zsjType = zsj.wkbType()
zsjCrs = zsj.dataProvider().crs().authid()

# Loop on feature, create for each one a new layer
# and use each new layer as an input for processing algorithm input
for idx, feat in enumerate(zsj.getFeatures()):

    mem_layer = QgsVectorLayer(
        f"{layerTypes[zsjType]}?crs={zsjCrs}",
        f"mylayer_{idx}",
        "memory"
    )

    mem_layer_data = mem_layer.dataProvider()
    attr = zsj.dataProvider().fields().toList()
    mem_layer_data.addAttributes(attr)
    mem_layer.updateFields()
    mem_layer.addFeature(feat)

    clip = processing.run("qgis:clip", {
        'INPUT':si,
        'OVERLAY': mem_layer,
        'OUTPUT':'memory'
    })
    print(clip['OUTPUT'])
```

Do not hesitate to make feedback if any issue as I did not tested directly all the code but some chunks only

Comment: Thank you very much for the code. It is functional! This is the main part of my script. Now, I joined attributes from the overlayed layer. The last part is to merge or create a layer from all clipped parts. I created an empty list where I used the .append function. I have qgis._core.QgsFeature object(). It is possible to export this list to the vector layer? Or how I could merge them into one layer?

Comment: Sorry for multiple edits in comments..., a better link e.g https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/vector.html#directly-from-features

Comment: `zsj.addFeature(feat)` should be `mem_layer.addFeature(feat)` I think

Comment: `mem_layer_data.addFeature(feat)` actually.